# python rename image in a folder

Tags: python, rename

I'm trying to rename all files in a folder (suppose the name is already sorted from 0 - 20), I want to rename them starting at a specified number.
It really changes all images' names but the order is messed up.
Right after it changes the name of 1st image, it jumps to the 10th image before going back to 2nd image.

Is there something wrong with the loop?

```
for file_name in os.listdir(folder):
    
    source = folder + file_name
    
    destination = folder + str(count) + ".jpg"
  
    os.rename(source, destination)
    count += 1
```

Comment: file names are sorted in alphanumerical order. you'll need to parse the number from string to int and sort on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`listdir` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir):

> The list is in arbitrary order

You'll want to apply a natural sort to that returned list to get it in the order you expect.  See for example [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4836710/5987)